# HBase fails to start in a simple configuration

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, opensuse

Now I have a pc whose OS is OpenSUSE 13. It is a datanode of a HDFS cluster.
I am now trying to start a hbase in a standalone mode.
Here is my configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>file:///tmp/hbase-hadoop</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>zj-solomonl-linux2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2222</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Very simple, isn't it?
And I have my /etc/hosts like this:

```
fe00::0         ipv6-localnet 
ff00::0         ipv6-mcastprefix 
ff02::1         ipv6-allnodes 
ff02::2         ipv6-allrouters 
ff02::3         ipv6-allhosts 
10.19.228.112   zj-solomonl-linux2 zj-solomonl-linux2
10.19.228.112   localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback
```

But when I start the hbase, I got this:

```
2014-10-06 15:57:26,215 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=zj-solomonl-linux2:2222 sessionTimeout=10000 watcher=master:36573, quorum=zj-solomonl-linux2:2222, baseZNode=/hbase
2014-10-06 15:57:26,223 INFO  [main-SendThread(zj-solomonl-linux2:2222)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server zj-solomonl-linux2/10.19.228.112:2222. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2014-10-06 15:57:26,224 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2222] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /10.19.228.112:38630
2014-10-06 15:57:26,224 INFO  [main-SendThread(zj-solomonl-linux2:2222)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to zj-solomonl-linux2/10.19.228.112:2222, initiating session
2014-10-06 15:57:26,225 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2222] server.ZooKeeperServer: Client attempting to establish new session at /10.19.228.112:38630
2014-10-06 15:57:26,225 INFO  [SyncThread:0] persistence.FileTxnLog: Creating new log file: log.15
2014-10-06 15:57:26,282 INFO  [SyncThread:0] server.ZooKeeperServer: Established session 0x148e47685bd0000 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /10.19.228.112:38630
2014-10-06 15:57:26,282 INFO  [main-SendThread(zj-solomonl-linux2:2222)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server zj-solomonl-linux2/10.19.228.112:2222, sessionid = 0x148e47685bd0000, negotiated timeout = 10000
2014-10-06 15:57:26,285 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x148e47685bd0000 type:create cxid:0x1 zxid:0x16 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase
2014-10-06 15:57:26,296 INFO  [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Node /hbase already exists and this is not a retry
```

And this:

```
 2014-10-06 15:57:26,770 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x148e47685bd0000 type:create cxid:0xd zxid:0x18 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/master Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /hbase/master
```

And this:

```
    2014-10-06 15:57:36,050 INFO  [M:0;zj-solomonl-linux2:36573] master.MasterFileSystem: BOOTSTRAP: creating hbase:meta region
2014-10-06 15:57:36,060 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed suppression of fs shutdown hook: Thread[Thread-5,5,main]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ShutdownHook.suppressHdfsShutdownHook(ShutdownHook.java:204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ShutdownHook.install(ShutdownHook.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.startup(JVMClusterUtil.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.startup(LocalHBaseCluster.java:425)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2785)
2014-10-06 15:57:36,751 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: HBase 0.98.6.1-hadoop1
```

And this:

```
2014-10-06 15:57:36,856 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=zj-solomonl-linux2:2222 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=clean znode for master, quorum=zj-solomonl-linux2:2222, baseZNode=/hbase
2014-10-06 15:57:36,868 INFO  [main-SendThread(zj-solomonl-linux2:2222)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server zj-solomonl-linux2/10.19.228.112:2222. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2014-10-06 15:57:36,871 WARN  [main-SendThread(zj-solomonl-linux2:2222)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: 拒绝连接
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
2014-10-06 15:57:36,977 WARN  [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper, quorum=zj-solomonl-linux2:2222, exception=org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
2014-10-06 15:57:36,977 INFO  [main] util.RetryCounter: Sleeping 1000ms before retry #0...
2014-10-06 15:57:37,975 INFO  [main-SendThread(zj-solomonl-linux2:2222)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server zj-solomonl-linux2/10.19.228.112:2222. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2014-10-06 15:57:37,975 WARN  [main-SendThread(zj-solomonl-linux2:2222)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: 拒绝连接
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
2014-10-06 15:57:38,075 WARN  [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper, quorum=zj-solomonl-linux2:2222, exception=org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
2014-10-06 15:57:38,075 ERROR [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper getData failed after 1 attempts
2014-10-06 15:57:38,075 WARN  [main] zookeeper.ZKUtil: clean znode for master, quorum=zj-solomonl-linux2:2222, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to get data of znode /hbase/master
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.getData(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.getDataNoWatch(ZKUtil.java:777)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MasterAddressTracker.deleteIfEquals(MasterAddressTracker.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZNodeClearer.clear(ZNodeClearer.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2785)
2014-10-06 15:57:38,076 ERROR [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: clean znode for master, quorum=zj-solomonl-linux2:2222, baseZNode=/hbase Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.getData(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.getDataNoWatch(ZKUtil.java:777)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MasterAddressTracker.deleteIfEquals(MasterAddressTracker.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZNodeClearer.clear(ZNodeClearer.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2785)
2014-10-06 15:57:38,076 WARN  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker: Can't get or delete the master znode
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.getData(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.getDataNoWatch(ZKUtil.java:777)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MasterAddressTracker.deleteIfEquals(MasterAddressTracker.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZNodeClearer.clear(ZNodeClearer.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2785)
2014-10-06 15:57:39,075 INFO  [main-SendThread(zj-solomonl-linux2:2222)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server zj-solomonl-linux2/10.19.228.112:2222. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2014-10-06 15:57:39,176 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x0 closed
2014-10-06 15:57:39,176 INFO  [main-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
```

It always fails!

I have also tried to set the localhost entry as 127.0.0.1 as other stackoverflow answer's suggestion. No thing better happens.
I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Your hbase is not backed by hdfs but by the filesystem check this [config file](https://github.com/dzlab/bigdata-samples/blob/master/dzlab-hbase/src/main/resources/hbase-site.xml) and this [blog post](http://elsoufy.blogspot.fr/2014/06/gettint-started-with-hbase.html), you should use  something like `hdfs://namenode/path/to/toorDir` for hdfs.

Comment: Do you mean that I can not run it in standalone mode? Because the namenode is another machine that I have to couple it